# проблема с web.py и mysql

Tags: mysql, python, uwsgi

Разворачиваю свой проект на боевом сервере и каждый день сталкиваюсь все с новыми и новыми проблемами..

Я настроил связку nginx+uwsgi+web.py

Запуская тестовое приложение, я спокойно подключаюсь к базе данных и вывожу из нее данные.

Но подключиться из основного приложения не получается. Даже к тестовой БД . Пишет

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")
```

файл для подключения bd выведен в отдельный python модуль config.py Ни чего кроме подключений в нем нет...

Как такое может быть что одно приложение подключается а другое нет? Как решить проблему? Помогите пожалуйста... Не сплю вторую неделю с настройкой сервера, уже сил нет.

Последние строчки лога выглядят примерно так

```
170606  0:01:41  InnoDB: Operating system error number 11 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
170606  0:01:41 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
170606  0:01:41 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
170606  0:01:41 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
170606  0:01:41 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB c                                                              reated
170606  0:01:41 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files fu                                                              ll of
170606  0:01:41 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be caref                                                              ul: do not
170606  0:01:41 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
170606  0:01:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
170606  0:01:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
170606  0:01:41 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
170606  0:01:41 [ERROR] Aborting

170606  0:01:41 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: А что у Вас слушает мускл? Порт или сокет? `netstat -nlp | grep mysql && netstat -nlp | grep :3306` 3306 стандартный порт, можно подключатся и по порту и по сокету. И какой статус у сервиса? Запущена?

Comment: `netstat -nlp | grep "mysql\|3306"`

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв.
`netstat -nlp | grep "mysql\|3306"` выдал следующее

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28761/mysqld
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     60608    28761/mysqld        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
`
Cтранно то, что, подключаюсь из тестового приложения все ок, отключаюсь, запускаю основное и хрен, а если подключиться снова к тестовому, то все ок при том что к той же самой bd... Нервов уже не хватает, больше года работы над приложением и уже 2 недели без сонных ночей в настройке сервера... Хоть на Azure переходи...

Comment: Выложите код подключения для вашего и для тестового, вы не забыли указать порт мускл?

Comment: я его копипапстил... Сейчас применил новые права доступа и группу с пользователем www-data и все равно не работает((

Comment: Выложите код, как Вы подключаетесь?

Comment: В тестовом
`db = web.database(dbn='mysql',
    user='root',
    pw='pass',
    db='pl',
    port=3306,
    host='127.0.0.1')

web.config.debug = False
`


в основном
`db = web.database(dbn='mysql',
    user='root',
    pw='pass',
    db='pl',
    port=3306,
    host='127.0.0.1')

web.config.debug = False`

Права, группа и пользователь совершенно одинаковы